# Where to get "Form 1099-MISC" for year 2017? (You’d think this would be easy...)

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-1099

On the [IRS Website](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-1099-misc-miscellaneous-income) for current year, there is "Form 1099-Misc" for 2018. The 2018 form is due by the end of January 2019. If we click [Prior Year](https://www.irs.gov/taxonomy/term/18566) link, we get forms for 2016.

I need "Form 1099-Misc" for 2017 which is due to be turned in by the end of January 2018.

Where is it? Please no paid services. Just the PDF.

Answer (score 28):

On the IRS page that you linked, in the “Other Items You May Find Useful” section, there is a link that says:

[All Form 1099-MISC Revisions](https://apps.irs.gov/app/picklist/list/priorFormPublication.html?value=1099-misc&criteria=formNumber&submitSearch=Find)

You’ll find the [2017 Form 1099-MISC](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/f1099msc--2017.pdf) there.

Comment: What's with the big scary warning at the beginning of the form?

Comment: There's nothing like a section called 'Previous Years' eh?

Comment: Alternatively, [search for "1099"](https://apps.irs.gov/app/picklist/list/formsPublications.html;jsessionid=0qHpvUq1u_AFgUz5adKHIgtGjuzpICT3yoVzL4_c.-?indexOfFirstRow=25&sortColumn=sortOrder&value=1099&criteria=formNumber&resultsPerPage=25&isDescending=false) using their own search form. Or if they have a consistent naming, then it should be appended with `_17` on their file name, e.g. https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1099msc_17.pdf

Comment: So, it turns out the form there is not able to be filed with the IRS, hence removing marking the answer as correct. I'm going with a paid online service after all. Thank you everyone for the info!